# AWS Kinesis Firehose: how to put multiple files containing JSONs using aws cli & bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have >100 files where each line is a json. It looks something like this (no commas & no []):

```
{"one":"one","two":{"tree":...}}
{"one":"one","two":{"tree":...}}
...
{"one":"one","two":{"tree":...}}
```

To be able to use aws firehose put-record-batch, file needs to be in the format:

```
[
  {
    "Data": blob
  },
  {
    "Data": blob
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to put all of these files to aws Firehose from terminal.

I'm looking to write a shell script that looks something like this:

```
for file in files
do
  aws firehose put-record-batch --delivery-stream-name <name> --records file://$file
done
```

So there're 2 questions:

1. How to transform the files into the applicable format
2. And, how to iterate through all the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *.json;
do
    jq -s . "${file}" >${file}.tmp && mv ${file}.tmp $file    
done
```

This will read all the json file in the current directory and change it into the desired form and save to the file .

OR if you do not have `jq` here is alternate way using `python's` json module.

```
for file in *.json;do
  while read line ; do 
      echo $line | python -m json.tool 
  done < ${file} |awk 'BEGIN{print "["}{print}END{print "]"}'
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without jq? Only using bin/bash commands

Comment: IMO , there would be , but it would not be recommended as `jq` is json aware tool unlike others. so they somewhere  will make some mistake. they cannot be as robust as `jq`.

Comment: this is somethig basic `sed -r 's/\{|,/&\n/g;s/\}/\n&/g' input.json |awk 'BEGIN{print "["}{print}END{print "]"}'` you may need to improve it further.

Comment: @stepandel  can you try second part of the answer if you have python installed in your shell this should work

Comment: I'm running a Linux VM on aws ec2 and ideally don't want to install anything on it. So hoping there's a way to do it with just bash

Comment: I have added one more in the answer